# Html style to align an image to the right of an input box

Tags: html

I am using Twitter bootstrap 3.0 and razor views.

How can I align the image in the below div to the immediate right of the artist text box ?

```
<div id="artist"class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Artists, new { @class = "col-lg-2 control-label" })
    <div class="container">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Artists, new { placeholder = "Artist name",@class="form-control", id="artistinput"})  
        <img onclick="AddArtist()" id="plusartist" src="\Content\bootstrap\img\plus-button.png" class="img-thumbnail"/>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Artists)
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap 3.0. ? Also what are you using to generate @Html.TextBoxFor... ? May I assume that the result is something like : <input type="text" class="form-control" ... ?

Comment: If you could, add your code in **jsfiddle**, or make same situation, with simple html e.x. I need to see all CSS concept to help you.

Comment: I am using Twitter bootstrap 3.0 and razor views.

Comment: What about the `.pull-left` class